# Optimizing multiple Textures for better performance in Windows + Pascal + SDL_2_0_5

Tags: windows, textures, sdl, pascal, sdl-2

I'm making a multiplayer game for Windows with pascal and SDL 2.0.5. 
I load 510 dots as Textures for the spaceship and procedurally make them form trails of the wings (there is no air in space, but who cares! it's cool). Below you can se pic and code related.

Now. There will be 7 more spaceships on screen and that makes the game crawl. Not mentioning the various other particles that will be in the game, generated by combination of multiple SAME textures. Is there a way to optimise this? Load the Texture and some how instance it one time? What is the best performance approach to the problem?

[image]

```
var
  //TRAILS
kentro2:array[1..255]of pSDL_Point;
TC:array [1..255] of PSDL_Texture;
TC2:array [1..255] of PSDL_Texture;
gwnia2:array [1..255] of double;
TCRect:array [1..255] of PSDL_RECT;
TCRECT1:array [1..255] of PSDL_RECT;
sdlFlip2 : PSDL_RendererFlip; 

{..}

FOR J:=1 TO 255 DO
    BEGIN
      tc[J]:= IMG_LoadTexture( sdlRenderer, 'trail10001.png' );
      tc2[J]:= IMG_LoadTexture( sdlRenderer, 'trail10002.png' );
    end;

{..}

FOR J:=1 TO 255 DO
     BEGIN
       NEW(TCRECT[J]);
       NEW(TCRECT1[J]);
       new(kentro2[j]);
     end; 

{..}

  IF ((METRITISTRAILS<255) AND (TRAiLSbool=false))THEN
      BEGIN
    trailscontainer:=METRITISTRAILS;
      end
      else
      begin
       TRAiLSCONTAINER:=255;
     trailsbool:=true;
       end;

      IF (METRITISTRAILS=255)THEN
   BEGIN
    METRITISTRAILS:=0;
   end;
    METRITIStRAILS+=1;





   gwnia2[METRITIStRAILS]:= -SHIPIDX;
   kentro2[METRITIStRAILS]^.X:=KENTRO^.X;
   kentro2[METRITIStRAILS]^.Y:=KENTRO^.Y;

   TCRECT[METRITIStRAILS]^.x:=RECTTEX2^.x;
   TCRECT[METRITIStRAILS]^.y:=RECTTEX2^.y;
   TCRECT[METRITIStRAILS]^.h:=RECTTEX2^.h;
   TCRECT[METRITIStRAILS]^.w:=RECTTEX2^.w;

       TCRECT1[METRITIStRAILS]^.x:=RECTTEX^.x;
       TCRECT1[METRITIStRAILS]^.y:=RECTTEX^.y;
       TCRECT1[METRITIStRAILS]^.w:=RECTTEX^.w;
       TCRECT1[METRITIStRAILS]^.h:=RECTTEX^.h;     

 SDL_RenderCopyEX(sdlRenderer,tc[METRITIStRAILS],tcrect1[METRITIStRAILS], TCRECT[METRITIStRAILS],gwnia2[METRITIStRAILS],kentro2[METRITIStRAILS],sdlflip);
 SDL_RenderCopyEX(sdlRenderer,tc2[METRITIStRAILS],tcrect1[METRITIStRAILS], TCRECT[METRITIStRAILS],gwnia2[METRITIStRAILS],kentro2[METRITIStRAILS],sdlflip);


       FOR J:=1 TO TRAiLSCONTAINER DO
           BEGIN
               if j<>metritistrails then
              begin


                 TCRECT[j]^.x+=THYMISOUGIATRAILSX-rect2^.x;
         TCRECT[j]^.Y+=THYMISOUGIATRAILSy-rect2^.y;  


                SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod( tc[J],j-giaalpha);
                SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod( tc2[J],j-giaalpha);
  SDL_RenderCopyex(sdlRenderer,tc[j],tcrect1[j], TCRECT[j],gwnia2[j],kentro2[j],sdlflip2);
   SDL_RenderCopyex(sdlRenderer,tc2[j],tcrect1[j], TCRECT[j],gwnia2[j],kentro2[j],sdlflip2);
              end;
              SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( sdlRenderer, 0,0, 0, 0 );

           end;
          giaalpha+=1;
              if giaalpha>=255 then
              giaalpha:=0;
```

Comment: Why do you load so many instances of the same texture? You only have two, just draw them many times.

Comment: I thought mistaken that each instance holds the attributes of the dot(pos, center, angle). That was a mistake. Thank you I tried with only just 2 and it works. But when I add 7 more spaceships even with 2 textures loaded, the instances are too many, and the game crawls. Any idea on that?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a huge number to me, don't think it should be *that* slow. May be you can prerender your trail to single texture (either offline in graphics editor or in runtime via rendering to texture once). It is kind of trivial with e.g. GL/d3d but I'm not sure SDL rendering API allows you to draw texture multiple times with different parameters as single draw call.

Comment: A lot of GL font systems are based on the system to copy small parts of textures to various positions on the screen. The first 10000 shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The case is that with 8 spaceships I have 4000 1x1 pixel textures procedurally positioned every frame. With 8 spaceships the framerate drops A LOT  (like 80%).

Comment: Probably you use an old fashioned way of opengl then. Upload only coordinates and let the shader iterate and draw. You can even rotate/stretch them individually using the geometry shader.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort OP doesn't use GL directly, SDL handles that (actually, it is far more likely to be using d3d on windows). And yes, it does single draw per rectangle, hence slowdown.